# turtlebot pointcloud_to_laserscan building problem

Tags: ros, turtlebot, build, pointcloud-to-laserscan, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried to build pointcloud_to_laserscan from turtlebor package, and I got this errors:

```
/home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/src/cloud_to_scan.cpp: In member function 'void pointcloud_to_laserscan::CloudToScan::callback(const ConstPtr&)': /home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/src/cloud_to_scan.cpp:137:29: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'output.boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator-><sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >()->sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >::header = (& cloud)->boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator-><const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>
>()->pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::header' /home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/src/cloud_to_scan.cpp:137:29: note: candidate is: In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h:51:0,
                 from /home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/src/cloud_to_scan.cpp:33: /opt/ros/hydro/include/std_msgs/Header.h:55:8: note: std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void>
>& std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void>
>::operator=(const std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void>
>&) /opt/ros/hydro/include/std_msgs/Header.h:55:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const pcl::PCLHeader' to 'const std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void>
>&' make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/cloud_to_scan.dir/src/cloud_to_scan.cpp.o] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cloud_to_scan.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/build' make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have ROS-Hydro and Ubuntu 13.10
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99546/turtlebot-pointcloud_to_laserscan-building-problem/) by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS Hydro, all ROS messages were removed from PCL. This requires that code be updated to use pcl_conversions, see the migration guide for details: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL

You might check if there is a version already updated for Hydro, or if you are using the Turtlebot, check out the replacement depthimage_to_laserscan which offers significantly better performance

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2